# GAS - Extend script running time

Tags: google-apps-script

Based on [LINK](https://script.gs/bypass-script-execution-timeout-programmatically/)  I learned how to extend the script running time of Google Apps Script when it exceeds the maximum running time of 5 minutes.

It works but I am not sure if I did it in the correct way. I am facing some issues as described below.

Coming from the mainfunction I handover the variable "t" as starting point for the loop and I call the function Foto_function.
There is a trigger if time exceeds the limit of 240 seconds.

```
 if (isTimeUp(today)) {

                  // schedule a trigger for a different function

                SpreadsheetApp.activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(t);
                  ScriptApp.newTrigger("Foto_function_Repeat")
                      .timeBased()
                      .everyMinutes(1)
                      .create();
                  break;
               }
```

.....

```
function isTimeUp(today) {
      var now = new Date();
      return now.getTime() - today.getTime() > 240000;
      // 30000 = 30 seconds; this is the threshold limit
      // you are free to setup your own threshold limit
    }
```

When the time is exceeded a clone of the Foto_function (called "Foto_function_Releat") will be started. The variable "t" will be handed over to the clone function. The the time is running from scratch and if the 240 seconds have been reached it switches back to the original Foto_Function.

At the end when the loop is finished the triggers will be deleted....

```
if (t == lastrow_Fotos + 1) {
          stopp_triggers();
          break;
          }
```

.....

```
function stopp_triggers(){
                var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
                for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
                    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
                    sendmail();
                }
    }
```

BUT: I receive round about 8 to 12 E-Mails with exactly the same content and I do not know why? Is there something wrong with my code?

.....HERE IS THE FULL CODE....and an E-Mail will be sent to me, so I know the script is completely finished.

```
function mainfunction(){

//do some stuff;

SpreadsheetApp.activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(2); // handover the variable "t" to the Foto_function
Foto_function();

}


function Foto_function(){

var today = new Date();
var Geodata = getSheetById(1702838837);
var lastrow_XX = Geodata.getRange(1, 1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow(); //Last row in column A of sheet GEODATA
value_t = SpreadsheetApp.activeSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  for (var t = value_t; t <= lastrow_XX + 2; t++){

      if (t == lastrow_Fotos + 1) {
      stopp_triggers();
      break;
      }

if (isTimeUp(today)) {

              // schedule a trigger for a different function

            SpreadsheetApp.activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(t);
              ScriptApp.newTrigger("Foto_function_Repeat")
                  .timeBased()
                  .everyMinutes(1)
                  .create();
              break;
           } 

            else {
                //do some stuff;
            }

}
}



function Foto_function_Repeat(){

var today = new Date();
var Geodata = getSheetById(1702838837);
var lastrow_XX = Geodata.getRange(1, 1).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow(); //Last row in column A of sheet GEODATA
value_t = SpreadsheetApp.activeSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  for (var t = value_t; t <= lastrow_XX + 2; t++){

      if (t == lastrow_Fotos + 1) {
      stopp_triggers();
      break;
      }

if (isTimeUp(today)) {

              // schedule a trigger for a different function

            SpreadsheetApp.activeSheet.getRange("A1").setValue(t);
              ScriptApp.newTrigger("Foto_function")
                  .timeBased()
                  .everyMinutes(1)
                  .create();
              break;
           } 

            else {
                do some stuff;
            }

}
}



function stopp_triggers(){
            var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
            for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
                ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
                sendmail();
            }
}


function sendmail(){

var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var mailname = user.split('@');

mailname = mailname[0];
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: user,
      subject: 'GAS-Task is finished',
      htmlBody: 'Hello, the task is finished!!!'
    });


    }

function isTimeUp(today) {
  var now = new Date();
  return now.getTime() - today.getTime() > 240000;
  // 30000 = 30 seconds; this is the threshold limit
  // you are free to setup your own threshold limit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code block

```
             ScriptApp.newTrigger("Foto_function_Repeat")
                  .timeBased()
                  .everyMinutes(1)
                  .create();
```

makes you create a trigger that will fire `function Foto_function_Repeat()` every minute.
So every minute `var t` will be set back to `= value_t` and will increment within the `for` loop until the `if (t == lastrow_Fotos + 1)` condition is fullfilled. 
`function stopp_triggers()` will delete all triggers, but will not kill the executions of `repeatFunction()` that have been fired already in the time span between the start of the first `repeatFunction()` run and the moment where `t == lastrow_Fotos + 1` is fullfilled.

### I recommend you to increase the execution time of the trigger from `.everyMinutes(1)` to e.g `.everyMinutes(4)`.

Also, I recommend you to implement logs with counter variables at strategic positions of the code, so you can monitor its execution and verify that secuence of the call of different functions is as intended.

[Script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service.html) are useful to store values in between to script runs. You can store and retrieve counter variables, so you do not start every time looping from zero again.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds reasonable. Could you please show how you would adapt the code, if it is not too complex?

Comment: I cannot adapt your whole code for you, since I do not know enough about its purpose, but if you implement for `timeUp` a smaller time threshold value than the parameter in `.everyMinutes()`, you should be able to avoid the problem of multiple simultaneous script runs. Eg, set the threshold to 200000 ms.

Comment: This did not work. The variable "t" is going up and down. It should constantly increase but it doesn't.

Comment: This means that you still have several parallel executions. The `.everyMinutes()` trigger does not execute exactly on the second, you might want to have a larger safety margin to avoid overlapping. As mentioned before, implement Logger.logs to monitor executions, and also have a look at View->Executions

Comment: I already use properties for setting "t" instead of grabbing out of a sheet. I have set time is up to 10 seconds and the trigger to 1 minute (I cannot set to 4, I can set 1,5,10,15....). But still "t" is going up and down. I am finished, do not know what else to do.

Comment: Do you use properties for setting and retrieving of `t`  both in `Foto_function()` and `Foto_function_Repeat()`?

Comment: Yes, I will try another thing. I think I know where the problem is....will come back on it.

Comment: The script of repetition was a misunderstanding on my side. I do not need to start a new trigger in the Repeat-Function. And I do not have to go back to the original function. I just need to start the trigger once! I did the mistake to start several triggers. Is still not perfect but better!

Comment: If you need the trigger only once, then it is easy. You can do something like `ScriptApp.newTrigger("Foto_function_Repeat").timeBased().after(durationMilliseconds).create()` to create a single trigger that will fire after the indicated amount on ms.

Comment: No I need the trigger several times, so repetition after 1 minute is okay. What I mean...I did start more than one triggers self-repeating after 1 minute...this was producing chaos ;-)